# Teapot Riddle no.26

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

So I've noticed the `Teapot` riddles are rising in popularity and I figured I would give them a try; also, it didn't help that it was recommended by [@user474343](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/42452/user477343) for me to do so. Good luck to you all!

---

### The Rules

- I have one word which has several (2 or more) meanings.
- Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
- You try to figure out the word with my Hints.

---

### The Puzzle

First:

> My first teapot is a unit of measurement.

Second:

> My second teapot is to understand.

Comment: Yay, you made one! DVL1 $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is your teapot

> FATHOM?

Because

> Fathom is a nautical length measurement and it means to understand.

Comment: As always sir, you are quick on the draw. I'll mark when I can. I knew this was too easy lol

Answer (score 4):

The answer is

> Fathom

My first teapot is a unit of measurement.

> A fathom is 6 feet?

My second teapot is to understand.

> I can't fathom how hard the question is