# Teapot Riddle no. 30

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I really enjoy these puzzles, [Jannis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/52327/jannis) told me to write my own.  Here's my attempt.

Rules (from Jannis):
I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings**.
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
You try to figure out the word with my Hints.

First Hint:

> My first teapot is good when thought out.  
> It, usually, brings other people more money.

Second Hint:

> My second teapot is good when practiced.  
> It often is followed by lots of money.

Third Hint:

> My third teapot is also good when practiced.  
> It brings happiness, sometimes money.

Fourth Hint:

> My fourth teapot is good when kept up.  
> It brings excitement.

Final Hint:

> When my first teapot is bad, it is just ignored.
> When my second teapot is bad, it is heckled.
> When my third teapot is bad, it is laughed at.
> When my fourth teapot is bad, it causes doctor's visits.

Bonus Hint 1:

> My first teapot is part of how movies are made.
> My second teapot had a TV show named after it.
> My third teapot has a trilogy about it.
> My fourth teapot has been a part of many movies.

Bonus Hint 2:

> If good, my first teapot could help break a ceiling
> If fast, my second teapot could break wood
> If high, my third teapot could break glass
> If poor, my fourth teapot could break ankles

Will add hints if no one guess it first :-)

Good luck, have fun!

[no. 29](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72919/teapot-riddle-no-29)
[no. 28](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72882/the-perpetual-teapot-no-28)
[no. 27](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72880/teapot-riddle-no-27)
[no. 26](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72877/teapot-riddle-no-26)

Comment: It's not 'work' or?

Comment: @Jannis what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the word is

> pitch

Teapot 1:

> Pitch an idea, for a movie or business venture for example

Teapot 2:

> Pitch a baseball, earning money, cheers or jeers, maybe breaking a bat

Teapot 3:

> Pitch of voice, like an opera singer breaking a wine glass

Teapot 4:

> Pitch as in field, where soccer/football is played, kept up by mowing, causing injuries if in bad condition

Comment: Yup! That's it! When did you get it?

Comment: I saw the question last night and was trying to make the word "shot" work, but couldn't quite get it to fit all the clues. Then this morning I was listening to a podcast and <answer> was talked about in one of the contexts of this puzzle, and everything clicked.

Comment: Nice!  Glad you got it!

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> a Program?

because

> a thought through concept brings much money,
>  as well as a computer programm, which needs practice
>  a TV show brings lot's of fun
>  a pro g(r)amer make's exitement? but if he smashes the tastatur he goes to doctor since he needs a new hand... even i broke once my table

Comment: Good thought, but not what I'm thinking :-)

Comment: @Greg i've edited

Comment: It's definitely a good guess, however ROT13(cebtenz) isn't correct

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a stab:

> Rings
>  1:  (Not sure on this one)
>  2: Boxing Ring (good when practiced, lots of money, heckled when bad, Tv Series)
>  3: Ring for finger (good when practiced, sometimes money (wedding), laughed at when bad, Lord of the Rings)
>  4: Nuva Ring (good when kept up, excitement, dr visit when bad)

Comment: Good thinking! Not what I was going for, but +1 from me!

Answer (score 1):

Could it be

> Drive
>  1. A drive like for charity.
>  2. Car driving - TV show Drive (about car race) - winners get a lot of money.
>  3. Driven with ambition - definitely brings happiness and money if it's your career
>  4. Umm... S** drive

Comment: Nope! Thanks for guessing though :-)

Comment: Dang! I thought I had it for a moment! :/

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be not

> work

hmm

> 1. a thought trough work/task is useful
>  2. practicing job is also useful
>  3. practicing an output is also useful...
>  4. when having a cool job it's happening that you do everyday sth exciting or
>  when sth works after working on it it's exciting

Comment: You are correct, it is not that... Maybe use the final hint?  Or maybe my clues are too broad...

Comment: @Greg the clues are ok ... I'm kind of brute forcing, what's not quite bad since other then can see: a) this isn't it and b) that guy's dumb af :P