# Teapot Riddle no.32

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

Riddle 32:
Rules:
I have **one word** which has **several** (2 or more) **meanings**.
Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...)
You try to figure out the word with my Hints.

First Hint:

> My first teapot needs physical powers to be build up
>   My second teapot needs no physical power to be build up
>   My third teapot needs also physical powers, to be build up

Second Hint:

> My first teapot needs no physical power to dissolve
>   My second teapot needs mental power to dissolve
>   My third teapot needs half a week to dissolve

Third Hint:

> My first teapot lets us move
>   My second teapot lets us want to move
>   My third teapot lets us not move

Final Hint:

> My first teapot is a task of the body
>  My second teapot is a problem of the mind
>  My third teapot is a problem of the body

*This riddle has 2 possible solutions*

Good luck and have fun :)
[last riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72923/teapot-riddle-no-30)

Comment: its 32 now.....

Comment: @NaeemShaikh whatt!! my fault ill change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since most still apply, then could it be...

> "**strain**"? or **tension**

**First Hint:**

*My first teapot needs physical powers to be build up*

> This is the basic meaning!

*My second teapot needs no physical power to be build up*

> because you need no strength to cause stress!

*My third teapot needs also physical powers, to be build up*

> because this is also a physical injury, requiring physical powers!

**Second Hint:**

*My first teapot needs no physical power to dissolve*

> Same : just let it go !

*My second teapot needs mental power to dissolve*

> you need strong mental skills to resist mental pressure

*My third teapot needs half a week to dissolve*

> Depends on people, but this is some base recovering time

**Third Hint:**

*My first teapot lets us move*

> Obviously!

*My second teapot lets us want to move*

> again : boss pressure!

*My third teapot lets us not move*

> Outch... it huurts!

**Final Hint:**

> My first teapot is a task of the body  : 
>  Muscle job!

-

> My second teapot is a problem of the mind :
>  Stress!

-

> My third teapot is a problem of the body :
>  The injury !

Comment: I'll mark as right since it's completely right: my word is originally Rot13(grafvba) But that's a synonym with the exact same meaning so: Congratualtions :)

Answer (score 4):

Let's have my first try :

> may it be "**pressure**"?

**First Hint:**

*My first teapot needs physical powers to be build up*

> pressure used for steam engine, for example

*My second teapot needs no physical power to be build up*

> pressure applied by humans to humans : working under pressure!

*My third teapot needs also physical powers, to be build up*

> atomspheric pressure, that needs a lot of physics to build up!

**Second Hint:**

*My first teapot needs no physical power to dissolve*

> just let it go!

*My second teapot needs mental power to dissolve*

> you need strong mental skills to resist mental pressure

*My third teapot needs half a week to dissolve*

> atmospehric pressure may take time to lower down

**Third Hint:**

*My first teapot lets us move*

> steam power!

*My second teapot lets us want to move*

> boss pressure!

*My third teapot lets us not move*

> too hot in there!

**Final Hint:**

> My first teapot is a task of the body  : 
>  The pressure applied by your heart to share the blood over your whole body

-

> My second teapot is a problem of the mind :
>  Mental pressure : can be applied, but also suffered

-

> My third teapot is a problem of the body :
>  Blood overpressure... (not sure of the real english name of it)

Comment: For the last answer: ROT13(uvtu oybbq cerffher) :-)

Comment: @Marvin It's not the right answer but you're almost there